# Increment variable with a button

Tags: java, android

i've made a simple counter program, where i click the plus or minus button and it adds or removes 1 from a counter.

I would like to be able to add more counters: ex. counter1, counter2, counter3 etc.
Here's an example of how i'm doing now with 2 counters, but as you can see i have declared my variables, and i would like to generate them automaticly

```
int counter, counter2;
ImageButton add, sub, add2, sub2, btnSet;
TextView display, display2;
```

And here's how i am using the plus button

```
// Plus button setup
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            display.setText(""+counter);
            Vibrator vibr = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

            vibr.vibrate (20);
```

Comment: "but as you can see i have declared my variables, and i would like to generate them automaticly" - means?

Comment: Call `display.invalidate()` after you changed something.  Otherwise, tell us what is wrong.

Comment: Id like to make an "add counter" button, and then generate 4 variables counter3, add3, sub3, display3. 
And when i press the add counter again then it would generate counter4, add4, sub4, display4.
And so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class that holds the information related to your increment button:

```
class IncrementButton {
    int step;
    int counter;
    ImageButton add, sub;
    TextView display;

    public IncrementButton(int step) {
        this.step = step;
        add = ...
        sub = ...
        display = ...

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter += step;
                display.setText("" + counter);
                Vibrator vibr = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibr.vibrate (20);
            }
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

and put objects of that class in a list - for example for 3 buttons:

```
List<IncrementButton> buttons = new ArrayList<IncrementButton> ();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    IncrementButton btn = new IncrementButton(i + 1);
    buttons.add(btn);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll go and study a bit about lists because it's not fully clear to me how this works, but i think i got this :)
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Create your won widget that contains counter, 2 buttons (for add and subscribe) and text view,
put all you logic there (on click listener etc...), and just hold list of how-many-instances-that-you-want in your activity.